# jsRender and paging

Tags: jquery, paging, jsrender, custompaging

I am trying to get **[jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/jsrender.js)** and paging to work, but I am somewhat new to jsRender and jquery for that matter.
I have tried to modify **[this](http://encosia.com/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/)** to work with jsRender instead, but I am having only limited success.

1. I am getting an exception when I click the "next page" link (see the code). The exception is "JsRender Error: Unknown template: "#items" - I think it happens because the code is overwritten on subsequent data fetch, but I am not sure how to fix it - any help is appreciated.
2. Can anybody suggest some hints to create a numeric paging mechanism as well? E.g. "<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... >> - clicking on the "..." will reset the numerics to "<< 11 12 13 .." and so on.

Here is my code for paging.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="paging.aspx.cs" Inherits="paging" EnableViewState="true" %>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body,table {font-family: Verdana; font-size:12px;}
    th,td {text-align:left;}
    div.paging a {padding:0 3 0 3;}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/js/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadData(1);
        loadCount();
    });

    function loadData(page) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paging.aspx/getData",
            data: "{'Page':'" + page + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                updatedata(msg);
                UpdatePaging();
            }
        });
    }

    function loadCount() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paging.aspx/ItemCount",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                lastPage = Math.ceil(msg.d / 10);
                UpdatePaging();
            }
        });
    }

    var currentPage = 1;
    var lastPage = 3;

    function UpdatePaging() {
        if (currentPage != 1) {
            $('#PrevPage').attr('href', '#');
            $('#PrevPage').click(PrevPage);
        }
        if (currentPage != lastPage) {
            $('#NextPage').attr('href', '#');
            $('#NextPage').click(NextPage);
        }
    }

    function NextPage(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        DisplayProgressIndication();
        loadData(++currentPage);
    }

    function PrevPage(evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       DisplayProgressIndication();
       loadData(--currentPage);
    }

    function DisplayProgressIndication() {
        // Hide both of the paging controls,
        //  to avoid click-happy users.
        $('.paging').hide();
        // Clean up our event handlers, to avoid memory leaks.
        $('.paging').unbind();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>ID</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="list">
    <script id="items" type="text/x-jsrender">        
    <tr>     
    <td>{{>Title}}</td>
    <td>{{>Date}}</td>
    <td>{{>ID}}</td>
     </tr>
    </script>
</tbody>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatedata(msg) {
            $("#list").html($("#items").render(msg.d));
        }
     </script>

<br />

<a id="PrevPage" class="paging">&laquo; Previous Page</a>
<a id="NextPage" class="paging">Next Page &raquo;</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The paging.aspx.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Web.Services;


public partial class paging : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int pageSize = 10;
    static int totalRows = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static IEnumerable getData(int Page)
    {
        DataTable dt = DataAccess.returnList(Page, pageSize);
        var data = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   select new
                   {
                       Title = d.Field<string>("Title"),
                       ID = d.Field<int>("ID"),
                       Date = d.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString()
                   };
        totalRows = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TotalRows"].ToString());
        return data;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static int ItemCount()
    {
        return totalRows;
    }
}
```

The json data I get back looks like this in raw request:

```
{"d":[{"Title":"Bla bla","ID":123,"Date":"04-07-2012 10:05:00"},
    {"Title":"Bla bla","ID":124,"Date":"26-06-2012 12:50:00"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your example:

```
$(function(){
    var data = [{Title:'title 1', Date: 'date 1', Id: 1},
                {Title:'title 2', Date: 'date 2', Id: 2},
                {Title:'title 3', Date: 'date 3', Id: 3}];

    $("#list").html($("#items").render(data));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9mBhd/

You need to check: data and selectors in your code, also note that you will remove template with `html()` from `#list` in your example.

Comment: Hi - I am not sure I understand your answer. I can get the data out and show fine in the initial request. The problem occurs when I am trying to load new data by hitting "next page".

Comment: @Perelli Move template outside `<tbody id="list">`

Comment: that worked more or less (the error goes away), but something funny happens when I click next or previous buttons. It reloads data, and shows new results, but then it can start cycling through data for each click I make. Maybe this is some asynchronous stuff that is causing it to reload multiple times. Not sure how post this is jsfiddle.

Comment: On initial request it calls loadData() 1 time, when clicking on "next page" afterwards it will call loadData() 2 times. Clicking on "next page again" will call loadData() 4 times, and it keeps doubling for all requests.

Comment: @Perelli Yes, this is asynchronous stuff, you can disable navigation after click and enable after `success`.

Comment: I might be wrong - but I thought that evt.preventDefault() would actually do it? Can you provide a code sample to illustrate your point - I still learning jQuery/jsRender.

Comment: @Perelli Here is demonstration of your problem (click fast many times on next): http://jsfiddle.net/9mBhd/1/

Comment: Thanks for that, but I do not see this is an optimal solution to block the user 1,5 seconds. The data takes only around 50-60 ms to load, so it will result in bad user experience. The thing is - I only click once, and wait a few seconds before I click again - but the loadDate calls keeps multiplying even if I wait for e.g. 10-15 seconds between each click. Is not possible to determine when the async stuff is done and then e.g. enable links again?

Comment: @Perelli Oops, I answer on another question ;) As I understand now, you asking about multiple clicks? As I can see, after each request you attach new click event in `UpdatePaging`.